# How can I create a testing script with GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, testing, assembly, gdb

I have a set of inputs that I want to use to test my program so see what input will hit a break point. I want to create a script to test these inputs one by one and if it hit the break point, print or save the result to a file.
Please let me know if it's possible and if yes, how can I do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have exactly understood what you are asking for. But if I understood correctly, you want to write a program that:

- Starts another program
- Passes some pre-defined input to the other program
- Checks if some breakpoint in the other program is hit

I don't know if this is possible using `gdb`, but it would be possible to write your own debugger:

- Start the program to be tested using `fork` and one of the `exec` functions (such as `execlp`)
- Before the `exec` function call `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,0,0)`
- Call `waitpid`; if `exec` succeeded, the program will be stopped immediately. The "status code" (second argument) returned by `waitpid` will be 0x57F (assuming an x86 CPU).
- If `waitpid` returns another exit code, `exec` failed and you cannot continue.
- Use `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,...)` and `ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT,...)` to modify the program: You place a break point to some address by replacing the instruction at that address by a "breakpoint" instruction (on x86 CPUs: `int3` which is byte `0xCC`)
  This means:
  You have to know the addresses (not the line numbers) of the break points and write `0xCC` to each address using `ptrace()`.
  Because `PTRACE_POKETEXT` can only modify 4 bytes (x86_32) or 8 bytes (x86_64) at once, you first have to read the old values of these 4 or 8 bytes using `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT`, modify 1 of 4 or 8 bytes and write all 4 or 8 bytes back.
- If your program is not always loading to the same address (due to ASLR etc.) you can read the program counter (using `PTRACE_PEEKUSER`): It should be the (actual) address of the entry point of the program.
- Call `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,pid,0,0)` to start the program being tested
- Call `waitpid` to wait for the program to be stopped or to exit
- If `waitpid` returns 0x57F as "status code", you are in the breakpoint. You may now use `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` to stop your program.
- You may use `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` to check the value of the program counter (`rip` on x86-64) so you know which breakpoint has been hit. Note that the program counter may be the address of the breakpoint **plus 1**, so if a breakpoint at address 0x12340000 has been hit, `rip` may be 0x12340001.
- If `waitpid` returns any other value with the low byte 0x7F, the program caused an exception. You should use `kill(pid,SIGKILL)` to finally stop it.
- Otherwise (if the low byte returned by `waitpid` is not 0x7F), the program has finished without causing an exception and without hitting any breakpoint.

Here some example code:

```
int pid, code;
long tmpLong;

pid=fork();

if(!pid)
{
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,0,0);
    execlp("program_to_be_tested","program_to_be_tested",NULL);
    exit(123);
}

waitpid(pid,&code,0);

if(code!=0x57F)
{
    /* Starting the program failed ... */
}
else
{
    /* Set breakpoints - here assuming x86-64 */
    tmpLong=ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA,pid,(void *)(address&~7),0);
    ((char *)&tmpLong)[address&7]=0xCC;
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA,pid,(void *)(address&~7),(void *)tmpLong);

    /* Continue the program */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,pid,0,0);
    waitpid(pid,&code,0);
    if((code&0xFF)!=0x7F)
    {
        /* Program did not hit a breakpoint
         * and did not cause an exception */
    }
    else if(code==0x57F)
    {
        /* Breakpoint hit */
        kill(pid,SIGKILL);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Program caused an exception */
        kill(pid,SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

To pass input to your program, you have two possible choices:

- Run the debugger multiple times:

  ```
  echo "Input to be tested" | ./myDebugger
  ```

  Because your debugger does not read from STDIN, the input will be passed to the program to be tested.
- Use `pipe` and `dup2` when creating the child process:

  ```
  ...
  pipe(pipes);
  pid=fork();
  if(!pid)
  {
      dup2(pipes[0],0);
      close(pipes[0]);
      close(pipes[1]);
      ...
  }
  close(pipes[0]);
  write(pipes[1],"Input to be sent to program", ...);
  ...
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfect.